# How to get WebRTC MediaStream to Node JS

Tags: node.js, server, webrtc, mediastream

I just want to know to get webrtc media stream to the node js server and serves it to the clients connected to that server.

I already created P2P WebRTC application with node js signalling server and it works fine. But now wants to route the media stream through the server. It should have low latency and delay to make it work at live server.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit). Like these

- [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/)
- [janus-gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/)
- [kurento](https://www.kurento.org/)

Here is a [github project](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms) where it is implemented using mediasoup.